# Can't Delete Data Store Index in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I was following the [Getting Started guide for Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/) and got to the step "Uploading your application". When I uploaded my application the Data Store Index never made it to status Serving, instead it went to Error.

I removed the datastore-indexes-auto.xml and created my own datastore-indexes.xml in the WEB-INF directory to see if that helps. When I tried uploading I get the "Cannot build indexes in ERROR" message as per [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/NLDsbDgg8qk)

I follow the instructions and comment out my `<datastore-index>` element and run `appcfg vacuum_indexes Guestbook\war`. This moves the index into Deleting state but then it eventually goes to ERROR again instead of being removed. I tried creating a new index and the same behavior happens for both. I can't get rid of them!

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: I am also having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Use the "report production issue" link in the admin console.